# Testing $H_0: \theta \leq 0$ versus $H_1: \theta > 0$: Find $c$ in rejection region so that probability of a type I error is $\alpha$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

My problem is as follows:

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from a $N(\theta,1)$ distribution, and consider testing $H_0: \theta \leq 0$ versus $H_1: \theta > 0$. Let $\Omega = \{\mathbf{X}: T(\mathbf{X}) > c \}$ be the rejection region, where $T(\mathbf{X}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. Find the value of $c$ such that the test has probability of type I error equal to $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a predetermined constant in $[0,1]$.

**What I know**: I know that a Type I error is when $H_0$ is true but we reject $H_0$, so we want to find $c$ so that $$ P_{H_0}(T(\mathbf{X}) \in \Omega) = \alpha \iff P_{H_0}(T(\mathbf{X}) > c).$$

I also know that $T(\mathbf{X}) \sim N(\theta,1/n)$. My difficulty is in the fact that the parameter space for the alternative hypothesis is $\Theta_1$ is an interval, namely $(0,\infty)$, rather than a single point. I just did a similar problem in which I calculated the probability of a Type II error given a test of the form $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta \neq \theta_0$. In that case I was able to translate the probability of failing to reject $H_0$ in terms of a $Z$-score, and obtained an answer for $c$ in terms of $z_{\alpha}$. But in this case I'm not sure how to proceed when the hypothesis is of the form $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0$ versus $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$.

Comment: You say: "I know that a Type I error is when $H_0$ is false but we fail to reject $H_0$ ...." Are you **sure** about that?

Comment: @BruceET: Oops! I was mixing up Type I and Type II errors. I believe I've corrected it now.

Comment: @Leonidas Mixing up between Type I and Type II errors is called a Type III error.